# How to find another way of using "&" in post request in Swift

Tags: php, swift, string, http

I am doing a post HTTP request in swift 4.2 and in one of my Strings I put in the parameters contain "&" but apparently the requests gets cut off after this symbol. I thought about replacing every "&" symbol with a unique placeholder and convert it back in PHP.

But is there are more elegant or easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URL encode your data (and decode it when you need to use it), that will make the ampersand into %26 which will stop it cutting off in your GET request.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the "&" with "%26" and then it's have to work :)

All Precent-encoding characters:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters

Answer (score 2):

You should probably minimize how much manual percent escaping you do. You might, for example, use `URLComponents` to build your URL and percent escape it for you:

```
guard var components = URLComponents(string: "http://example.com") else { return }
components.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "foo", value: "bar&baz")]
let url = components.url
```

That will result in:

> http://example.com?foo=bar%26baz

Answer (score 1):

PHP includes the [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) functions, and stift includes the [`.addingPercentEncoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1411946-addingpercentencoding) function.

This means you can replace with the encoded version of the '&' symbol which is '%26', or you can use swift's function

Then when you recieve this value you can use `urldecode( $escapedString )`, or just replace '%26' with '&', or just pull the values stright from the request with $_GET.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you use `addingPercentEncoding`, with the logical character sets, e.g., `.urlQueryAllowed`, that _won’t_ percent escape the `&`. You have to manually construct a character set that excludes `&` for use with `addingPercentEncoding`.

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand, as well as a few other characters, need to be encoded if they are within a query parameter otherwise they could be recognized as a delimiter of some sort.

You can encode a string for a query param in Swift like this:

```
let value = string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

let urlString = "https://example.com/?query=\(value)"
```

---

On the other side, your server will receive the encode param value but will need to decode it.

Comment: If `string` contains a `&`, this will _not_ percent escape it.